# SEARCH PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need mysql code or php to handle some search query

Lets say we have these 5 items in our store.

```
ID | TYPE   | Pattern

1. | Kilner | scissor
2. | Kilner | forcep
3. | Boyd   | scissor Small
4. | Boyd   | scissor large
5. | Boyd   | forcep
6. | Boyd   | clamp
```

**Could you help me mysql query to handle below operation**

If we search 'boyd' then numbers 3 4 5 and 6 should come up.

If we search 'scissor' then numbers 1 3 and 4 should come up.

If we search 'boyd scissor', numbers 3 and 4 should come up.

If they search' Kilner scissor' then only no 1 should display.

Let me know
thanks

Answer (score 2):

the way to do it in mysql is full text search

```
SELECT *, MATCH(field) AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3') AS score
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(field) AGAINST('word1 word2 word3')
```

look this tutorial http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: visit the link don't copy this answer

Comment: do you have any other option, it's too bit complicated

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search_var%'
```

PDO structure

```
$db = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE :mysearch");
$db->execute( array("mysearch"=>'%'.$mysearch.'%') );
```

Comment: sorry just added the table structure to the question

Answer (score 0):

The query you ask is a bit complex. You want to return matches in *both* columns, but if both columns match, then single matches have to be discarded.

This means, one way or another, run a query requiring two matches and one requiring one match, comparing the results and returning the appropriate set.

Performance-wise, I believe it is better to run one query that will fetch both, and then handle the results in PHP (you could handle them in MySQL through the use of a superquery).

So:

```
// We split keywords
$keywords = array_unique(preg_split('/\s+/', $search));
$inset    = array();
foreach($keywords as $keyword)
    $inset[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."'";
$sql_in   = '('.implode(',', $inset).')';

$query    = "SELECT *, IF(type IN $sql_in, 1,0)+IF(pattern IN $sql_in,1,0) AS matches FROM mytable WHERE (type IN $sql_in) OR (pattern IN $sql_in) ORDER BY matches DESC;";
```

The above uses the discouraged mysql_ functions. Using PDO, that would be:

```
$keywords = array_unique(preg_split('/\s+/', $search));
// Generate a (?,?,?..?) template as long as $keywords
$sql_in   = '('.implode(',', array_fill(0, count($keywords), '?')).')';

$query    = "SELECT *, IF(type IN $sql_in, 1,0)+IF(pattern IN $sql_in,1,0) AS matches FROM mytable WHERE (type IN $sql_in) OR (pattern IN $sql_in) ORDER BY matches DESC;";
$st       = $db->prepare($query);
$st->execute($keywords);
```

Note that the above uses **exact match**, so "Boyd" will retrieve a match with "Boyd", but "Boy" won't. Use the `%` matching character to change this behaviour.

Now we retrieve a table which is identical to MyTable but has one extra column, "matches", containing either 2 or 1. Can't contain 0 because of the `WHERE` limitation: one of the two matches must be true and count as 1.

The 2's will be returned first, so we can do

```
if (!isset($matches))
    $matches = $tuple['matches'];
else
    if ($tuple['matches'] < $matches)
        break;
```

that is, we save the first (and highest) value, and only accept that value for the subsequent tuples. As soon as an inferior match comes by, we exit the loop and close the cursor.

This may be done in MySQL with

```
SELECT * FROM ( the above query ) AS newTable
    WHERE matches = ( 
        SELECT MAX(matches) FROM ( the above query ) AS tmpTable
    );
```

but it incurs a performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search=array('byod','scissor');
$st=""; $st2="";
foreach($search as $value){$st.="type=%$value% or ";$st2.="pattern=%$value% or ";}
$st2=substr($st2,0,-3);
echo "select * from tablename where $st $st2";
```